# what are the ways to open MSI files in linux?

Tags: windows-installer

Actually i was tried with other tools like nsis,7Zip but i was not able to open msi file with nsis.
So is there any way to open msi file in Linux and to do some changes to that file.Please guide me regard this.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like [msitools](https://wiki.gnome.org/msitools) should be able to help you.

I've been able to extract some MSI files with `msiextract` from that package.